# Code for converting a compressed IPv6 adress into its long form

Tags: java, ip-address, ipv6

I would like to know, whether there is a library which I can use to convert a represenation of a compressed IPv6 adress (such as 0:9876:5700::9) into the long IPv6 form (in this case: `0000:9876:5700:0000:0000:0000:0000:0009).`

Answer (score 1):

This transformation will do the conversion:

```
ip = ip. replaceAll("^", "0000").replaceAll("::", "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000").replaceAll("^.*?(....)(?=:)|(?<=:)[^:]*(?=....$)", "");
```

The extra `replaceAll()` at the end ensures there are no extra zeroes in the first/final part, which caters for the leading/trailing address info ("0" and "9" in this case) being any number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.common.net.InetAddresses;
// Convert the short IPv6 address to a full version
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddresses.forString(shortIPv6); 
return inetAddress.getHostAddress();


import java.net.Inet6Address;
import java.net.InetAddress;
InetAddress inetAddress = Inet6Address.getByName(shortIPv6); 
return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
```